# How to configure PHPUnit to regard dataprovider error as failure and not warning?

Tags: php, phpunit

I run my PHP unit tests using PHPUnit. When a dataprovider fails to load, it results in a warning, instead of a failure.

Up until PHPUnit version 4, when a dataprovider fails to load, a failure is shown in the PHPUnit output.
Starting with PHPUnit 5, a warning is being issued instead. This is a problem for when running the tests using a script (for example in continuous integration) so I don't see the results.

Another difference is when running the code with PHP 5 vs PHP 7. When running the tests with PHP 5, instead of seeing the PHPUnit output I immediately get a PHP Fatal Error. With PHP 7 it only shows the failure/warning when PHPUnit gets to the failed test. This leads me to believe that this has something to do with the error_handler set by PHPUnit, that can catch the error that PHP7 throws but PHP5 doesn't.

Here is my PHP code:

```php
class TestTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provider_sample
     */

    public function test_sample($foo)
    {
        $this->assertString($foo);
    }

    public function provider_sample()
    {
        return [
            [ClassName::string] // no such class, this should fail
        ];
    }

    public function getDataset()
    {
        return new ArrayDataSet([]);
    }
}
```

Here are the results of running PHPUnit 4:

```
PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:        PHP 7.2.5
Configuration:  /home/some-path/phpunit.xml
Warning:        The Xdebug extension is not loaded
                No code coverage will be generated.

F

Time: 120 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Warning
The data provider specified for TestTest::test_sample is invalid.
Class 'ClassName' not found

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Failures: 1.
```

And here is the results of running the same code with PHPUnit 5:

```
PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.2.5
Configuration: /home/some-path/phpunit.xml
Error:         No code coverage driver is available

W                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 99 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

There was 1 warning:

1) Warning
The data provider specified for TestTest::test_sample is invalid.
Class 'ClassName' not found

WARNINGS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Warnings: 1.
```

The results of PHPUnit 4 is what I expect and want.
Is there a way to configure PHPUnit 5 and higher to behave the same?

Comment: Maybe in a general sense, in any data provider you need to first validate if you can indeed generate valid data, and if not, maybe throw an exception.  In this case, you can maybe use class_exists() to see if the valid data can be created, which is the ClassName object in this case.  And if not, then throwing an exception should create a test failure I would think.

Comment: Alternatively to throwing an exception, you may be able to use `$this->fail()` or `$this->assertTrue(false)` to manually fail the test, but I am not sure if those work inside a data provider method. You may be able to use `$this->assertTrue(class_exists('ClassName', true))`.

Comment: @Huy, this is too specific. I want that every time a dataprovider fails to properly resolve - to be notify about it. I.e. to get a failure and not a warning.

Comment: Maybe see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057013/execute-dataproviders-only-when-needed-in-phpunit . "...data providers are executed before both the call to the setUpBeforeClass static method and .. setUp method ...this is required in order for PHPUnit to be able to compute the total number of tests." So technically the dataprovider is executed before the first test in the class runs. It is not a part of a test but a part of the setup. So I am not sure if there is a way to make a test fail with a dataprovider - only as an error during setup. Maybe someone else knows of a better way

Comment: @Huy From PHPUnit's perspective there is no difference whether a class cannot be autoloaded or an exception is thrown from a data provider, they both end up as `PHPUnit_Framework_Warning`. PHPUnit doesn't suggest a way to change it, and @sebastian-bergmann is pretty firm on this: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2228#issuecomment-336609090

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly what you're asking for, but if you want to integrate PHPUnit with a continuous integration server (for example, Jenkins), then you can spawn a JUnit-compatible report with warnings reported as errors instead and tell Jenkins to use that instead of PHPUnit report.

To do that, you will need to extend JUnit logger shipped with PHPUnit:

```php
use PHPUnit\Util\Log\JUnit;

class MyJUnit extends Junit {
    public function addWarning(Test $test, Warning $e, float $time): void {
        $this->addError($test, $e, $time);
    }
}
```

And register it as a listener in `phpunit.xml`:

```xml
<listeners>
  <listener class="MyJUnit" file="MyJUnit.php">
    <arguments>
      <!-- 
        Print the output to the file instead of stdout 
        which is the default.
      -->
      <string>junit.xml</string> 
    </arguments>
  </listener>
</listeners>
```

Finally, go to Jenkins settings and add a JUnit job specifying the location of output file.

Comment: Thanks! With some adjustments, this is as close as I get to what I actually need.

Answer (score 0):

check the file name and import the

```
 require_once 'ClassName.php';
```

Comment: This indeed avoids the problem, but what I want to achieve is, in case it is **given** that _ClassName_ can not be loaded, I want a **failure** to be issued, not a **warning**.